# Can I transfer an overall stat_smooth line to a facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, facet-wrap

I'm working with multiple years of data (1995-2021) where I'm looking at growth rates of individuals within those years. I have one graph with all of the years and measurements combined and then a facet_wrap of the years separated. Is it possible for me to add the loess line of the combined years to the facet_wrap graphs? I know how to add the average from the aggregate function but I'd rather have the loess line of the graph containing all years.

```
ATPUdf<-as.data.frame(ATPU)
ATPUav<-aggregate(data=ATPUdf, Wing~Age, mean)

ATPU$Year <- as.factor((ATPU$Year))

atpu_grow <- ggplot(data=ATPU, aes(Age,Wing, colour=Year))+
  xlab("Age (days since hatch)")+ylab("Wing Chord (mm)")+
  geom_point(size=1)+
  stat_smooth(color="grey50", fill="grey70", size=0.8, method="loess")+
  theme_bw()
atpu_grow

atpu_grow2 <- ggplot(data=ATPU, aes(Age,Wing, colour=Year))+
  xlab("Age (days since hatch)")+ylab("Wing Chord (mm)")+
  geom_point(size=1, show.legend=FALSE)+
  stat_smooth(color="grey50", fill="grey70", size=0.8, method="loess")+
  theme_bw()+
  facet_wrap(. ~Year)
atpu_grow2
```

Comment: Can you make your code reproducible? I can't access the object `ATPU`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. All you have to do is to drop the facetting column from `geom_smooth()`'s  `data` argument.

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(2022)

# Dummy data
df <- data.frame(
  year  = rep(1995:2021, 5),
  value = cumsum(rnorm(5 * 27)),
  id    = rep(1:5, each = 27)
)

ggplot(df, aes(year, value)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = factor(id))) +
  geom_smooth(data = ~ transform(.x, id = NULL)) +
  facet_wrap(~ id)
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>